# Matplotlib plot only horizontal lines in step plot

Tags: matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to plot some step functions from a dataframe

```
df['s1'].plot(c='b', drawstyle="steps-post")
df['s2'].plot(c='b', drawstyle="steps-post")
...
```

The result looks like

[image]

I would like to have this only plot the horizontal lines, not the vertical lines connecting the jump points. I could not find a straightforward parameter for plot that would seem to do that. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no built-in option to produce a step function without vertical lines as far as I can tell. But you may easily build one yourself. The following uses the fact that `np.nan` is not plotted and cuts the line. So adding `np.nan` in between the steps suppresses the vertical line.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def mystep(x,y, ax=None, where='post', **kwargs):
    assert where in ['post', 'pre']
    x = np.array(x)
    y = np.array(y)
    if where=='post': y_slice = y[:-1]
    if where=='pre': y_slice = y[1:]
    X = np.c_[x[:-1],x[1:],x[1:]]
    Y = np.c_[y_slice, y_slice, np.zeros_like(x[:-1])*np.nan]
    if not ax: ax=plt.gca()
    return ax.plot(X.flatten(), Y.flatten(), **kwargs)
    
x = [1,3,4,5,8,10,11]
y = [5,4,2,7,6,4,4]

mystep(x,y, color="crimson")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This answer corresponds to the `drawstyle='steps-post'` keyword argument in `plt.plot()` for drawing step graphs i.e. the y-value of the flat line at any given x-value is equal to the y-value at the next smallest x-value from the passed x array. For example using the arrays in @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer, the y-value at x=1.5 equals the y-value at x=1 (i.e. y=5).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `hlines` is the "correct" (built-in) way to do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,3,4,5,8,10,11]
y = [5,4,2,7,6,4]

plt.hlines(y,x[:-1],x[1:])
plt.show()
```