# How to make the function line break without manually def a piecewise function?

Tags: python, matplotlib

For example:

```py
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=sp.linspace(0,100,500)
plt.plot(x,sp.floor(sp.sqrt(x)))
```

[image]

But what I want is

[[image: 2]]

Since there are so many discontinuities points, it's tired to pick all of them out manually.

Comment: Please see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44961184/matplotlib-plot-only-horizontal-lines-in-step-plot

Comment: In this case you can also use a scatterplot: `plt.scatter(x, sp.floor(sp.sqrt(x)))`

Comment: there is another way: `y[:-1][np.abs(sp.diff(y))>0.3]=sp.nan`